# is using display property for responsivness bad behaviour?

Tags: css, reactjs, display

I am trying to make my react app to look like an actual app when entered via a phone and for that im removing and showing a lot of cards depending on platform.

In my css i have a .mobile {display: false} when on screens wider than 768px and i have a .laptop {display: false} on screens less wide than 768px. It is working fine and looks good but im concerned if this is considered bad behaviour and may cause some unwanted behaviour? and if it is behaviour is there another way to achhieving the same effect? Thank you

Comment: I can't find a relation between this question and the one that made this closed. Curious!

Comment: Anyway, I would suggested you searching and using CSS flex with media screens as such in bootstrap grid system. You are not restricted with any css framework but you can use media screens and flext to make your website responsive. It is okay to write your own grid classes.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am using the ion grid and it is working very well, i just wanted to change some stuff witch was to hard for me to do with grid.